# How to use scrollViewWillEndDragging for different components?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I have `CollectionView` in `TabelViewCell` and I'm trying do paging and centring for `CollectionView`'s cells. But when I work with method

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>){}
```

it applies for TabelView and CollectionView. I know that these types inherited from UIScrollView and that's why this arises. What needs to be done to apply this method to only one type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by checking the type of scrollView:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if scrollView is UITableView {
        // Do your thing for the tableView.
    } else if scrollView is UICollectionView {
        // Do your thing for the collectionView.
    }
}
```